# Javascript onclick not running

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want a link, when clicked, to execute a javascript function.

Here is the javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeStyle() {
            var header = document.getElementbyId("header");
            var container = document.getElementbyId("container");

            header.style.display = "block";
            container.style.marginLeft = "auto";
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript:changeStyle()"><span>&#9776</span> MENU</a>
```

Currently, when the link is clicked, nothing happens. How would I make it so that the javascript actually changes the styles when I want it to?

EDIT:

Here is new code:

Javascript:

```
$('#selector').click(function() {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
    header.style.display = "block";
    container.style.marginLeft = "auto";
})
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="selector"><span>&#9776</span> MENU</a>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no question here.

Comment: Read about unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: There is something *inherently* wrong. You should avoid having variables (like a function) in the global namespace. Add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

Comment: _Is there something inherently wrong that I am doing?_  - **yes**, you should use [unobtrusive scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) instead.

Comment: @goldage5, please add a jsfiddle to illustrate, as it seems (by guessing), that your code does not work either because your html does not match js, or because styles set via js are the same as existing.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#selector').click(function() {
        var header =       document.getElementbyId("header");
        var container =     document.getElementbyId("container");
        header.style.display = "block";
        container.style.marginLeft =     "auto";
       })
      </script>

I modified my code to this, but its still not working.

Comment: `getElementbyId` is not a typo just in your post, it can be found from the production code too?

Comment: Yeah, it was also a typo in my code. I changed it, but still. Nothing.

Comment: So suddenly it's jQuery now ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the onclick attribute, not the href :

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeStyle();return false;"><span>&#9776</span> MENU</a>
```

A better idea would be to not use inline javascript

```
<a href="#" id="menu"><span>&#9776</span> MENU</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var a = document.getElementById('menu');

     a.onclick = function() {
        var header    = document.getElementById("header");
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        header.style.display = "block";
        container.style.marginLeft = "auto";
     }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsMVp/)

Note: the script must be placed after the elements

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that's still not working.

When I click the link, nothing happens.

Comment: For some reason I don't expect somebody with a gold badge in JS to suggest using inline event handlers.

Comment: @PeeHaa - when the question is how to apply an inline event handler, that's the answer they'll get. I've added another solution that gets rid of the inline js.

Comment: The question isn't about inline event handlers. The question is about OP finding some crap JS resource and not knowing any better. Thanks for the update though